# Matplotlib: WebAgg backend doesn't show any figures

Tags: python, browser, matplotlib, plot

I'm using Python 2.7.6 32-bit with Matplotlib 1.3.1. 
When I use the default backend, like in this example, the figure is shown:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

When I try to use WebAgg, the MPL page loads automatically, but without any figures:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('webagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

I tested this code on Windows and Ubuntu, using Firefox, Chrome and IE, without any success... 
Can somebody help, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The graph pops up it in a browser window. Do you get any other errors?

Comment: My recommendation is try and reinstalling Python and the matplotlib. That usually will fix hard to pin-down problems like yours.

Comment: Using VirtualBox, I tried a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 (comes with Python 2.7.3 included), then installed NumPy, Matplotlib and its dependencies. But still, the WebAgg browser window only showed the "Figure 1" link, without any figures. Clicking the link yields no results, either.

Comment: Is it possible that you somehow have a firewall blocking port 8888? (The default for webagg.)

Comment: I only tested this at work, so yes, maybe there is a firewall blocking the port. When I get home, I'll test the code again.

Comment: Tested it at home. Still not working...

Comment: I have the same problem (Py 2.7.6, MPL 1.3.1, x86_64). There is a escape sequence in generated JS code `fig = new figure(&#39;1&#39;, websocket_url_prefix);`. I believe `&#39;` should in fact be `'`.

Comment: I created [bugreport](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2975) for that.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching and testing, I ended up using pip to uninstall Matplotlib, then reinstall it (using the --upgrade command, just to be sure):

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

And it worked! Now I can see the WebAgg plots on the browser window!
Maybe I wasn't installing Matplotlib properly...
Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE:** As of June, 2022, Matplotlib (MPL) is now on version 3.5.2. This post is from 2014 and refers to MPL version 1.3 for Python-2.7 found in the Ubuntu Software Center so it's installed in `/usr/` which is part of the `root` environment. Therefore, the post is outdated and obsolete, and I may delete it.*

Update to the lastest development version, Matplotlib-1.4.x. Install in virtualenv using

```
$ pip install -e git@github.com:matplotlib/matplotlib.git
```

Then the OP's commands work on all platforms. There is also a new [embedded webagg example in the matplotlib master branch on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_webagg.py) that works on all of my systems (Windows-7x64, Ubuntu-14.14 and Xubuntu-14.14).

Using the OP's commands with Matplotlib-1.3.1, I get mixed results depending on which platform I use. On one machine (Ubuntu-14.14) I was able to show the figure if I used `sudo` to execute the OP's commands:

```
$ sudo python  # XXX: not normally recommended!!!
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('webagg')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot(range(10))
>>> plt.show()
```

This works both in a virtualenv and in the Ubuntu distribution version of matplotlib.

While on a VMWare Player virtual machine (Xubuntu-14.14 hosted on Windows-7x64) I was able to show the figure using the OP's commands **without** `sudo`. On a 3rd (Windows-7x64) machine I am still unable to get the figure using the OP's commands both with and without admin rights. I also changed `matplotlib.rcParams['webagg.port']` to 8080 and 8000 but that also did not work.

On Ubuntu-14.14 using matplotlib installed from the distribution's repository, you will see the following traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg.py", line 381, in get
'matplotlib.png'), 'rb') as fd:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mpl-data/images/matplotlib.png'
```

It has nothing to do with why the image doesn't appear; this error only appears on Linux machines in which the mpl-data folder is not where `matplotlib.backends.backend_webagg` expects it to be, but is actually in `/usr/share/matplotlib/`. Specifically `backend_webagg` is looking for the file `matplotlib.png` which it uses as the favicon for the web browser tab, and actually Tornado will still serve the page even if it doesn't find this file, although unfortunately it still issues this error.

If you use a virtualenv you will not see the favicon error.

Using Matplotlib-1.3.1 without `sudo` on Ubuntu-14.14 and on the Windows-7x64 machine I get the same "figure 1" link issue that @allisonmuller was getting in the comment above.

Comment: For God sake, don't use `sudo` when you don't have to.

Comment: @RedEyed I totally agree. This answer is from 2014, before conda, before `venv` was part of the standard distribution, and before folks were accustomed to using virtualenvs for everything, so I think (it's hard to remember) I was talking about when using the version of MPL in the Ubuntu software center. Perhaps I should go back update this post. I mean it is so out of date. Python-2.7??? ha!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Mark Mikovski's answer, I found that if you add a symbolic link as follows

cd /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/

ln -s /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data mpl-data

this seems to resolve the issue